How to prove that a $k$-tuple root of an equation $f(x) = 0$ is a root of $f^{(k-1)} (x) = 0$ but not of $f^{(k)} (x) = 0$?
I am reviewing The Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics (4th edition, 2008), edited by David Nelson.
In the section multiple root we have:

For any equation $f(x) = 0$ a multiple root is also a root of the first derived equation $f'(x) = 0$. ... In general, an $n$-tuple root is a common root of the equation itself and of all the derived equations up the the $(n-1)$th, but not of the $n$th derived equation.

(It does of course go without saying (and indeed, Nelson does not say it) that $f$ needs to be at least $n$ times differentiable. In fact, it can be considered a mistake not to state this.)
When $f$ is a polynomial function, it is trivially easy to prove this; prove it for a double root and then use induction.
For the general function where $f$ is not necessarily a polynomial, I am not at all sure where to start.
Could we use the fact that a function can be modelled by a (possibly infinite) Fourier series, thus reducing our $f$ to a polynomial? Can we jump from the finite to the infinite in this way?
Or is there a general way of proving Nelson's statement without resorting to Fourier analysis?
EDIT: The actual "definition", if it can in fact be called that with a straight face, is:

multiple root A repeated root of an equation. For example, the cubic equation
$$x^3 - 3x^2 + 4$$
has factorized form
$$(x - 2) (x - 2) (x + 1)$$
The roots are $-1$ and $2$, and the value $2$ appears twice, i.e. it is a double root.

So now we have to formally define "repeated root", which Nelson does not attempt.

The quoted sentence sounds like a definition of 'multiple root' (so no proof required). If it's not, what definition are you starting from?

@QC_QAOA: "A repeated root of an equation." Granted, this is not a definition as such at all. I have added a full expansion of what Nelson actually says in an edit.

The first quote is very likely Nelson's definition of a multiple root, while the second quote is an example for a polynomial.

@BrunoB It doesn't read like a definition. It's the second paragraph, and it reads as though it's an example of a characteristic of a multiple root. If it is a definition, it's non-intuitive, and for sheer pedagogical purposes it's crying out for a demonstration of its "multipleness", that is, an extension of the example of polynomials (in which it is "intuitive" what "multiplicity" means in the concept of a root), and how one arrives at this from the definition from  the PoV of multiple differentiation.

The presented definition implies the following factorization : if $a$ is a $n$-tuple root of a (non-polynomial) function $f(x)$, then there exists a function $g(x)$, with $g(a) \neq 0$, such that $f(x) = (x-a)^ng(x)$, at least in the neighbourhood of $a$ (due to its $n^\mathrm{th}$-order Taylor expansion around $a$). And the result follows straightforwardly from this form, since
$$
f^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \left((x-a)^n\right)^{(i)}g^{(k-i)}(x)
$$
according to the general product rule. Nonetheless, it is to be noted that this result itself is often seen as an alternative definition of multiple roots and is actually used to "spot" them in practice.

Or by induction: $f(x) = (x-a)^ng(x)$ implies $f'(x)=(x-a)^{n-1}h(x)$ with $h(x)=ng(x)+(x-a)g'(x)$ and $h(a)=ng(a)\ne0$. Thus $a$ is a root of $f'$ with multiplicity $n-1$.
